# appcelerator titanium on windows keeps on crashing - can i find out why?

Tags: appcelerator

*How do i find out why appcelerator titanium just crashed, and what can i do with this info?*

On windows, my appcelerator titanium keeps on crashing. I'm unsure if this  is a hardware issue - my laptop is about 2 years old, but has 4 gig ram and isn't too slow. It runs phpeclipse, java eclipse and pycharm fine. Heck, there have been times i've had two of the above open at the same time and its been fine.

But for some reason, titanium appcelerator just... crashes. It might last a few minutes, and then *BAM* it just exits. No error, no warning. Just gone.

I'm assuming this isn't enough to go on - so!

*How do i find out why appcelerator titanium just crashed, and what can i do with this info?*

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these are emulator or Titanium development tool related issues

Though I love the Titanium Mobile development tools, I've had odd issues with them at times.  I've had to restart Android-based apps several times to get them to deploy or run linked to the debugger.  If it is being really difficult I might perform a Project->Clean and close out all the tools and start them up again.  Sometimes after starting an Android project, it just losing connection so images disappear from the emulator.

Though iOS debugging seems more reliable, I've had issues with that as well.  For no particular reason my app will just shutdown.  Usually I'll get some feedback on why it stopped and usually more informative than for Android.

When my Android project fails, I just suck it up and start stepping through the application from the beginning.  Almost always I'll find it is some variable I typo-ed or didn't provide a valid value for on the Android.  For some reason, I get a message back almost all the time with iOS Simulator, but on Android it just hangs or dies.

If you are specifically indicating that Titanium Studio crashes on you for no reason, I've never had a problem with the IDE itself.  I've left that running for days at a time without closing it on both a MAC and a PC and never had an issue.